# Dropzone fallback does not fire any triggers

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using dropzone and have the following init function.

```
    Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
            url: '/path/to/handler.ashx',
            paramName: 'file',
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 20,
            forceFallback: true,
            init: function () {
                console.log('init'),
                this.on("sendingmultiple", function (files, xhr, formData) {     //event fired for each added files
                    console.log('sendingmultiple');
                    function() ValidateAllFiles();

                });
                this.on("successmultiple", function (file, data) {   //event for each successful upload
                    console.log("done");
                    DisplayMsg();

           });
        }
```

This work perfectly if the browser support dropzone. However, the sendingmultiple and successmultiple functions do not get triggered if i am in fallback mode. (nothing get wriiten into console)

This is my html markup.

```
<form id="filedrop" runat="server" action="/path/to/handler.ashx">
        <div>
            <div class="fallback">
                <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                <input type="submit" id="btnFallBack" value="Upload"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Does dropzone support these triggers even in fallback mode or i have to manually do it using button click event? If the later is true, then how can i get the array of file object like i did in the sendingmultiple function?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: forcefallback is for debugging purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

yea, i was right. I refactor my code so the dropzone sendingmultiple and fall back button click event triggers ValidateAllFiles(). After that, i call the Upload() method from code behind in the button click event. The Upload() method is the same method used by dropzone for uploading files.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the Upload() method?